# Table view doesn't bounce correctly when modifying constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm implementing a simple view that consists of UIView with a Table view below it.

I implement the scrollViewDidScroll and I change the UIView top constraint, which works fine:

```
        headerTopConstraint.constant = -scrollY - 65
```

(-65 is the original constraint)

The problem is, when changing the constraint constant programatically, I don't get the smooth table view bounce when scrolling down when there's no more content to scroll down to.

Instead it just "tries" to bounce but it immediately goes back to the original position. Example: http://jmp.sh/rTBfzCM

If I remove just that one line of code, the bounce works perfectly fine: http://jmp.sh/AtVYwPy

The table view has a top space constraint of 0 to the UIView.

Comment: It would be better if you use TableHeaderView instead of separate UIView. Then changing the headerView height according to the tableView contentOffset.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: @Jason why is the table view not bouncing correctly when programatically changing the constant of the top view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason that this is happening is because that line of code dynamically changes the constraint's constant **depending** on the current value of scrollY.

Now, I presume this is linked to the scrollview's y value. Which, since the "bounce" animation is affecting this value, it also changes the constraint's constant as well. In **your** specific line of code, I think it just so happens that it is "cancelling out" the action of the scroll/bounce, which leads to the weird jittery behaviour that you're seeing. By removing that line of code, you're essentially removing this link, thereby freeing the scrollview bounce animation from the constraint's effects.

Why exactly are you changing the constraint's constant? Perhaps trying a different formula will lead to your desired results.

---

**EDIT 1**
How about only updating the constraint's constant so long the tableView's visible frame is within the content size of the tableView? Something like the following (I don't know your variable names):

```
//Check if user has scrolled through all content within tableview
//If not, update constraint constant
if scrollY < self.tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height {
    headerTopConstraint.constant = -scrollY - 65
}
```

Comment: I'm changing that constant to move the top UIView further top, as you can see on this screenshot: http://jmp.sh/rTBfzCM It works fine, but unfortunately because the bounce is cancelling out, the animation on top is "janky". Is there another way to move the UIView without messing with the table view bouncing?

Comment: Your code in EDIT 1 seems to work flawlessly, I'll do some extra testing and I'll accept the answer shortly. Thanks!